# Convert a string to type "LuaFunction"

Tags: .net, lua, luainterface

I'm using the LuaInterface in .net for a large project I'm working on.  Is it possible to convert a string straight into a LuaFunction (similar to how LoadString() works?).

Comment: Doesn't LuaInterface have `LoadString` or some equivalent? If not, it's not a good interface to Lua, and it should probably change its name ;)

Comment: @Nicol You can run a string, yes.  I need to convert a string to a `LuaFunction` object.

Comment: `lua_loadstring` does not run the string. It loads it, converting it into a function which it pushes onto the stack. If LuaInterface has a special object for Lua functions, then LuaInterface's equivalent of `lua_loadstring` should return that special object. Or something else that is callable. What does it return?

Comment: It returns what the script it runs returns (e.g. `return 3` is my Lua script would return 3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LuaInterface has `LoadString`, that is how you get lua source code parsed into a `LuaFunction`, you can then use the `Call` method to execute the function.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Lua lua = new LuaInterface.Lua();

    LuaFunction func = lua.LoadString("return 5", "name for debugging");

    func.Call();
}
```